# How do I get projection from gml file

Tags: python, projection, gml, osgeo

I am trying to get the projection from a gml-file. This is the top of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <eop:Mask xmlns:eop="http://www.opengis.net/eop/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" gml:id="S2A_OPER_MSK_CLOUDS_SGS__20160914T145755_A006426_T31UCT_B00_MSIL1C">   <gml:name>MSK_CLOUDS pixels mask from data-strip S2A_OPER_MSK_CLOUDS_SGS__20160914T145755_A006426_T31UCT_B00_MSIL1C</gml:name> <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:8.7:32631">
      <gml:lowerCorner>300000 5690220</gml:lowerCorner>
      <gml:upperCorner>368340 5777580</gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>   </gml:boundedBy>   <eop:maskMembers>
    <eop:MaskFeature gml:id="OPAQUE.0">
      <eop:maskType codeSpace="urn:gs2:S2PDGS:maskType">OPAQUE</eop:maskType>
      <eop:extentOf>
        <gml:Polygon gml:id="OPAQUE.0_Polygon">
          <gml:exterior>
            <gml:LinearRing>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="2">320340 5776020 320520 5776020 320520 5775960 320700 5775960 320700 5775900 320760 5775900 320760 5775840 320820 5775840 320820 5775660 320760 5775660 320760 5775600 320700 5775600 320700 5775540 320340 5775540 320340 5775600 320280 5775600 320280 5775660 320220 5775660 320220 5775900 320280 5775900 320280 5775960 320340 5775960 320340 5776020</gml:posList>
            </gml:LinearRing>
          </gml:exterior>
        </gml:Polygon>
      </eop:extentOf>
    </eop:MaskFeature>
...
```

I tried using the code from https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataset = driver.Open(r'c:\data\yourshpfile.shp')

# from Layer
layer = dataset.GetLayer()
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
# from Geometry
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
spatialRef = geom.GetSpatialReference()
```

But both versions of spatialRef are None.

You can see from the file that it appears that the projection is given in the bounding box (at the very end of the first line it says  and then an envelope with the EPSG code in line 2.) (It doesn't say 'crs' or 'EPSG' anywhere else in the file).

Can anyone tell me how I access the projection information??

Can I maybe somehow get to the bounding box and then get the projection?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can find the projection information in the JPEG 2000 file provided by the Granules.

Using gdal it is:

gdalinfo *.jp2

gives you:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 21N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
    AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-57],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
....
```

Thats all I have